# How to exit program when the choice is not equal to "y"

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that would print 10 integers between 10-50 in an array and when you enter an integer outside 10-50 it would ask you if you want to try again or not. But when I try to enter "n" it would still continue to ask another integer. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define size 10


int main() {
    int i,arr[size],sum=0; 
    char ch;
do {
    
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
            printf("Input a number at index %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        
            if(arr[i] <10 ||arr[i] > 50 ){
            printf("entered number is not valid\n"); 
                printf ("Do you want to repeat the operation Y/N: ");
                scanf (" %c", &ch);
                
                }
            }
      
printf ("Do you want to repeat the operation Y/N: ");
scanf (" %c", &ch);
}
while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');



}
```

Comment: That specific block should have been in a while loop. Now you just get answer but you never ask for a number again.

Answer (score 0):

In this `if` statement you ask whether the user wants to continue or not, but do not handle the situation where the user enters an 'n'. You must enter a comparison followed by a `break` to exit the loop.

```
        if (arr[i] < 10 || arr[i] > 50){
            printf("entered number is not in the range 10..50\n"); 
            printf("Do you want to repeat the operation Y/N: ");
            scanf(" %c", &ch);
            // ADD THE FOLLOWING TO YOUR CODE
            if (ch != 'y' && ch != 'Y')
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe `if (ch != 'y' && ch != 'Y')` is more faithful to the title of the question?

Comment: Good point. But either case would fail to account for invalid characters (neither 'y' or 'n', as the string in the printf() indicates). Not that it would matter in this simple example, but it is something one should consider or at least leave explicit that any non-y character means No.

Comment: Generally, look for the explicit "continue" option — in this case `y` or `Y`.  Treat anything and everything else as the "stop" option.  But also be consistent.  When the user has made one mistake, trying to get them to fix the error handling response  is usually not sensible.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to make the user fix the response. I meant to make it more explicit that Y means yes and anything else means no. For example, change the string to something "Press Y to repeat the operation (default: N): " and anything else other than Y would mean no.